# Force Route to HTTPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302, laravel-backpack

I need help on setting up the laravel backpack on live server.

So at first i got trouble loading the asset since it used http for the image and css

> http://example.com/images/ and http://example.com/css/

I can solve that problem using this code I got

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

The assets are loaded correctly (it shows https://example.com/images/... when i inspeced it)

But somehow some crucial contents are not loaded with https, here's the screenshot:
[image: The Inspected Elements was for File Manaer Side Bar]

With the error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/admin/elfinder/connector' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Here's the code of the error

```
  <!-- This file is used to store sidebar items, starting with Backpack\Base 0.9.0 -->
  <li>
    <a href="{{ backpack_url('dashboard') }}">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
      <span>{{ trans('backpack::base.dashboard') }}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

There are several thing that didnt't get updated to https as well such as some CSS(from the vendor/crud), scripts, the post method, and the logo

I think that I can copy paste the meta tag to the backpack_url, but I have no idea where is it or how it works.

I am very new to this, any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your Laravel installation think that you are running on a `HTTP` server, while the client's request was made over `HTTPS`
These issues generally happen as a result of having a proxy in front of Laravel.

As a first point of call, ensure that your [trusted proxy configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) is correct. This will cause Laravel to trust the `X-Forwarded-Protocol` header, and intern to generate the correct `https` URLs.

If you can't get the proxy configuration working, you can always force `https` URL generation by adding this in your `AppServiceProvider`

```php
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Comment: thanks! i have found similar solution before "if(config('app.env') === 'production')" but that doesn't work and this work. probably because of the version(?)

Comment: @atymic, please can you help me look into this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72844902/deployed-laravel-website-on-digital-ocean-showing-blank-screen-and-attempting-to